# two way binding with dynamically created checkboxes

Tags: angular

How to done two way binding with dynamically created checkboxes ?

```
quali=[{class:"10",checked:false},{class:"12",checked:true},{class:"others",checked:true}];


<span *ngFor="let q_list of quali;let i=index" class="lists">
<input type="checkbox" class="checks" name="q_list" [(ngModel)]="q_list.checked">&nbsp;{{q_list.class}}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

it could be helpful to you

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp',[]);
    app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){
$scope.data=[{id:1,name:"one",check:true},{id:2,name:"two",check:false},{id:3,name:"three",check:true}]
    });
```

```css
table{
border-collapse:collapse;
width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
 <body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
    
    <table border="1">
        <tr ng-repeat="d in data">
            <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="data[$index].check">{{d.id}}</td>
            <td>{{d.name}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
 </body>
```

Comment: can you please rewritten the above code in angular 2.I tried it in angular 2 in the following way.                                                                                                               [(ngModel)]="data.check"                                                                                                       but nothing happen when changing condition as  true

Comment: still i can't solve the problem of two way binding with checkboxes? can you please help me???